# sql - Joining one table to two more tables

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to join a table (employee table) to two other tables (employee earnings and employee deductions) to display the amount for the particular type of earning and deduction of employee. Now, when my query duplicates the deduction when the employee has a record for two different types of earning and only one record for a deduction type. Employee has a one-to-many relationship to both earning and deduction tables.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT EmployeeMaster.EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, empEarnings.EarningCode, empEarnings.amt, empDeduc.DeductionId, empDeduc.amt 
from EmployeeMaster
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT EmployeeNumber, EarningCode, SUM(Amount) AS amt FROM EmployeeEarnings GROUP BY EmployeeNumber, EarningCode
) AS empEarnings
ON EmployeeMaster.EmployeeNumber = empEarnings.EmployeeNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT EmployeeID, DeductionID, SUM(Amount) AS amt FROM EmployeeDeduction GROUP BY EmployeeID, DeductionId
) AS empDeduc
ON EmployeeMaster.EmployeeNumber = empDeduc.EmployeeId
```

This returns (sample data only)

```
00001   First Name  Last Name   EARN       1000000.0000000000000000 SSS 1000.0000000000000000
00001   First Name  Last Name   EARN2      1000.0000000000000000    SSS 1000.0000000000000000
00002   First Name2 Last Name2  EARN       10000.0000000000000000   SSS 100.0000000000000000
00002   First Name2 Last Name2  EARN2      10000.0000000000000000   SSS 100.0000000000000000
```

The result is almost correct except, these employees only have one record of a deduction type. However, the result set duplicates the deduction table result which results to the sum of the total deduction being wrong (double of the supposed value) in my ssrs report.

How should I modify my query to fit these requirements, and also being able to generate an ssrs report in a format like:

```
Emp# First Name Last Name EarnType1 EarnType2 [...] DeducType1 DeducType2 [...]
#1    John        Doe       100000    100000        100        100
```

Comment: Each employee will only ever have 2 types of earning and 2 types of deductions?

Comment: No, an employee could have many of those.

Comment: Your desired result only shows 2. So now your saying your desired result can actually have an infinite amount of earning types and deduction types?

Comment: It is just a sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this differently.

What you need to do it produce a flat list of employees with earnings and deductions and then simply get your report to group the earning/deductions by code.

I've put together a simple script which does this. It's more or less the same as yours (obvious exception is the table names are variables so just swap these for you real table names)

```
DECLARE @EmployeeMaster TABLE (EmployeeNumber int, FirstName varchar(30), LastName varchar(30), MiddleName varchar(30))
DECLARE @EmployeeEarnings TABLE (EmployeeNumber int, EarningCode varchar(10), Amount float)
DECLARE @EmployeeDeduction TABLE (EmployeeID int, DeductionID varchar(10), Amount float)

INSERT INTO @EmployeeMaster 
VALUES (1, 'Bob', 'Smith', 'W'), (2, 'Jane', 'Jones', 'A')

INSERT INTO @EmployeeEarnings 
VALUES (1, 'Earn1', 1000000), (1, 'Earn2', 1000), (2, 'Earn1', 500000), (2, 'Earn2', 500)

INSERT INTO @EmployeeDeduction 
VALUES (1, 'Deduct1', 1000), (1, 'Deduct2', 800), (2, 'Deduct1', 500), (2, 'Deduct2', 200)

SELECT 
    emp.EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName
    , amts.AmountCode, amts.amt, amts.AmountType
from @EmployeeMaster emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 'Earning' as AmountType, EmployeeNumber, EarningCode as AmountCode
            , SUM(Amount) AS amt 
            FROM @EmployeeEarnings GROUP BY EmployeeNumber, EarningCode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Deduction', EmployeeID, DeductionID
            , SUM(Amount) AS amt FROM @EmployeeDeduction GROUP BY EmployeeID, DeductionId
) AS amts
ON emp.EmployeeNumber = amts.EmployeeNumber
```

All we've done here is union all the earnings and deductions into a single set and labelled each as whatever type they are (the amount type is not actually necessary unless you want you report to keep earnings and deductions bunched togther)

This gives us the following output

```
        EmployeeNumber  FirstName   LastName    MiddleName  AmountCode  amt     AmountType
        1               Bob         Smith       W           Deduct1     1000    Deduction
        1               Bob         Smith       W           Deduct2     800 Deduction
        1               Bob         Smith       W           Earn1       1000000 Earning
        1               Bob         Smith       W           Earn2       1000    Earning
        2               Jane        Jones       A           Deduct1     1000    Deduction
        2               Jane        Jones       A           Deduct2     800 Deduction
        2               Jane        Jones       A           Earn1       1000000 Earning
        2               Jane        Jones       A           Earn2       1000    Earning
```

Then I created a simple matrix reports, here's the design...

[image]

When we run the report, we get this...

[image]

As you can see there are two column groups, one to group by type (earn/deduct) and the other by code. The matrix will expand to accommodate any number of earning and deduction codes automatically.

Comment: Cool. I'll try this one!

Comment: Thank you! I've been there trying the union but I wasn't able to figure out how to group it accordingly.

Comment: Glad to help, we've all been in situations where we can't figure things out that turn out to be pretty simple. I've been doing this for so many years it's just experience !

Comment: ONE MORE THING!!  I just noticed a potential bug in the code. You need to change the `UNION` to `UNION ALL` just in case you have two identical earning or deduction entries as `UNION` will remove duplicates whereas `UNION ALL` will keep them. I've updated the answer

Comment: I have a question. Can you tell me how I could put a separate total column for these two?

Comment: If you want to total earnings and deductions separately within employee, then just right-click the `AmountCode` column group then `Add Total` then choose before or after. This will give you the totals. If you want to get a total of everything then you'll need to change you query to multiply your deductions by -1 then add a total at the `AmountType` group level.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Fiddle for the following http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71e8b/12:

I think this is a short-hand of what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  empNum INT,
  fName VARCHAR(20),
  lName VARCHAR(20),
  mName varchar(20));

create table empEarnings(
  eCode INT,
  empNum INT,
  earnAmount INT);

create table empDeduc(
  empDedId INT,
  emDedAmt INT,
empNum INT);

 INSERT INTO emp (empNum, fName, lName, mName)
 VALUES (1, 'a', 'ab', 'abc');

 INSERT INTO empEarnings (eCode, earnAmount, empNum)
 VALUES (1, 100, 1);

 INSERT INTO empDeduc (empDedId, emDedAmt, empNum)
 VALUES (1, 2, 1);

 INSERT INTO empDeduc (empDedId, emDedAmt, empNum)
 VALUES (2, 3, 1);
```

ANSWER:

```
;With getEarnSum AS(
SELECT ee.empNum, SUM(ee.earnAmount) AS 'sumAmount' FROM empEarnings ee
LEFT OUTER JOIN empDeduc ed ON ee.empNum = ed.empNum
GROUP BY ee.empNum)
SELECT emp.fname, emp.lname, emp.mname, cte.sumAmount FROM emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN
getEarnSum cte ON emp.empNum = cte.empNum
```

Comment: Thank you but the cte somehow does not return the desired output as it only returns the earnings and not the deductions and also does not group by the type of earning.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the deduction and earning result sets in a vertical fashion. Then use a matrix in SSRS to display in horizontal formal.

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee (EmployeeNumber int, LastName varchar(100), FirstName varchar(100))
CREATE TABLE #Earning (EmployeeNumber int, EarningCode varchar(10), Amount money)
CREATE TABLE #Deduction (EmployeeNumber int, DeductionCode varchar(10), Amount money)

INSERT INTO #Employee (EmployeeNumber, LastName, FirstName) VALUES
(1, 'Smith', 'John'),
(2, 'Doe', 'Jane')

INSERT INTO #Earning (EmployeeNumber, EarningCode, Amount) VALUES
(1, 'EARN1', 1.11),
(1, 'EARN2', 3.33),
(1, 'EARN3', 5.55),
(1, 'EARN4', 7.77),
(2, 'EARN1', 2.22),
(2, 'EARN2', 4.44)

INSERT INTO #Deduction (EmployeeNumber, DeductionCode, Amount) VALUES
(1, 'DEDU1', 2.22),
(1, 'DEDU2', 4.44),
(2, 'DEDU1', 1.11),
(2, 'DEDU2', 3.33),
(2, 'DEDU3', 5.55),
(2, 'DEDU4', 7.77)

SELECT EMP.EmployeeNumber, EMP.FirstName, EMP.LastName, DED.DeductionCode AS 'Code', SUM(Amount) AS 'Amount'
FROM #Employee AS EMP JOIN #Deduction AS DED ON EMP.EmployeeNumber = DED.EmployeeNumber
GROUP BY EMP.EmployeeNumber, EMP.FirstName, EMP.LastName, DED.DeductionCode
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP.EmployeeNumber, EMP.FirstName, EMP.LastName, ERN.EarningCode AS 'Code', SUM(Amount) AS 'Amount'
FROM #Employee AS EMP JOIN #Earning AS ERN ON EMP.EmployeeNumber = ERN.EmployeeNumber
GROUP BY EMP.EmployeeNumber, EMP.FirstName, EMP.LastName, ERN.EarningCode

DROP TABLE #Employee
DROP TABLE #Earning
DROP TABLE #Deduction
```

Comment: With regards to horizontal formatting, I would be able to do it with ssrs reporting service I believe.

Comment: @FriencyFernandez Good point. Using a matrix in SRRS would produce the horizontal format with the vertical result set from a query.

Comment: Yes I have actually tried it. I just need a result set that would allow me to produce the correct output. Thank you for your answer